# Instantiate object of a class under form class

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to windows forms. I am trying to instantiate a object of a public class and calling a method `drawBoard()` when button1 is pressed. Method `drawBoard()` through which I want to set the properties of pictureBox2. But the code didn't work.

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();                                                                   
        }

        public class gameBoard :Form1
        {
            public void drawBoard()
            {
                pictureBox2.ImageLocation = @"E:\My Data\DoCx\CS\3rd Sem\OOP\proj\images\a.png";
                pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;                      
            }            
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {             
            gameBoard a = new gameBoard();
            a.drawBoard();               
        }      
}
```

Also tried to implement this in other two ways:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            pictureBox2.ImageLocation = @"E:\My Data\DoCx\CS\3rd Sem\OOP\proj\images\a.png";
            pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            pictureBox2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;                               
        }    
 }
```

and

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();         
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            pictureBox2.ImageLocation = @"E:\My Data\DoCx\CS\3rd Sem\OOP\proj\images\a.png";
            pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;   
        }
    }
```

Both worked. Directly loads the image when the code runs. And also when the button1 pressed in second way. I wonder how to call the pictureBox properties when they defined in a method of a user-defined class.

Comment: Your internal class gameBoard doesn't know anything about a variable named pictureBox2. It cannot see that is something defined in the container class. Pass the pictureBox2 to the drawBoard method when you call it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you observe carefully then your `gameBoard` is defined as a nested class inside `Form1` and it also inherits from `Form` control, which doesn't make sense. You probably wan to have the class defined outside like (probably in a separate file)

```
    public class gameBoard
    {
        private PictureBox _box;
        public gameBoard(PictureBox box)
        {
            _box = box;
        }
        public void drawBoard()
        {
            _box.ImageLocation = @"E:\My Data\DoCx\CS\3rd Sem\OOP\proj\images\a.png";
            _box.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;                      
        }            
    }
```